# SASS error, custom ionic icon [ionic 3]

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

so basically, I'm trying to create a custom icon in my ionic 3 project, i know that ionic has provided us with their sample icon (e.g : ionicons)
however, I'm trying to made my custom ones to fit my project. 
I've been following the tutorial from this [link](https://yannbraga.com/2017/06/28/how-to-use-custom-icons-on-ionic-3/) to created the custom ones for my needs. The problem is when i try to build my project, i got this error

```
> Sass Error Invalid CSS after "}": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was
> ".icon@include makeI"
```

here's my complete scss code :

```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: 'icomoon';     src: 
> url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?ai7wni');    src: 
> url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?ai7wni#iefix')
> format('embedded-opentype'),
>   url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf?ai7wni') format('truetype'),
>   url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.woff?ai7wni') format('woff'),
>   url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.svg?ai7wni#icomoon') format('svg');
>   font-weight: normal;    font-style: normal; }
> 
> [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {     /* use !important to prevent
> issues with browser extensions that change fonts */   font-family:
> 'icomoon' !important;     speak: none;    font-style: normal;     font-weight:
> normal;   font-variant: normal;   text-transform: none;   line-height: 1;
> 
>   /* Better Font Rendering =========== */     -webkit-font-smoothing:
> antialiased;  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }
> 
> // ../assets/
> 
> 
> @mixin makeIcon($arg, $val) {   .ai-#{$arg}:before ,  
> .ion-ios-sm-#{$arg}:before ,   .ion-ios-sm-#{$arg}-outline:before ,  
> .ion-md-sm-#{$arg}:before ,   .ion-md-sm-#{$arg}-outline:before  {
>     content: $val;
>     font-size: 26px;   } }
> 
> 
> .icon@include makeIcon(home,'\e900'); .icon@include makeIcon(pipeline,
> '\e901'); .icon@include makeIcon(leave, '\e902'); .icon@include
> makeIcon(meeting-room, '\e903'); .icon@include makeIcon(logout,
> '\e904');
```

any kind of help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: remove `.icon` from `.icon@include makeIcon( ...`

Comment: solved! thanks mate, can you enlighten me? why should i remove that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.icon` from `.icon@include makeIcon( ...`

After creating your `mixin`, you can use it as a CSS declaration starting with `@include`

> A mixin lets you make groups of CSS declarations that you want to reuse throughout your site. You can even pass in values to make your mixin more flexible.

So your `.icon@include` is, basically, a syntax error.

Reference: [Sass Basics](https://sass-lang.com/guide)